# How to remove old files from the build dir when webpack --watch?

Tags: javascript, webpack

When my `webpack.config.js` is set to watch my source files, and the output files contain a hash, then each time the build successfully completes an entirely new set of built files exists. This quickly fills up the build dir with cruft!

How do I make `webpack` delete the old files on each build?

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  watch: true,
  output: {
    filename: '[name]-[hash:8].js'
  }
  ...
}
```

---

I recognize I could use `webpack-dev-server` to build in memory but that doesn't fit my current build process.

Answer (score 33):

Neither `clean-webpack-plugin`, `webpack-shell-plugin` is able to fulfill these requirements because it only runs before or after the entire webpack process, not just after build.

However With the [`on-build-webpack`](https://github.com/kossnocorp/on-build-webpack) plugin you can run an arbitrary function when the build is completed. In this function, unlink all the files in your build dir that are weren't just created. The `assets` object is passed into the function and has the set of assets just created.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const WebpackOnBuildPlugin = require('on-build-webpack');

const buildDir = '...path/to/your/build-dir/';

module.exports = {

  watch: true,

  new WebpackOnBuildPlugin(function(stats) {
    const newlyCreatedAssets = stats.compilation.assets;

    const unlinked = [];
    fs.readdir(path.resolve(buildDir), (err, files) => {
      files.forEach(file => {
        if (!newlyCreatedAssets[file]) {
          fs.unlink(path.resolve(buildDir + file));
          unlinked.push(file);
        }
      });
      if (unlinked.length > 0) {
        console.log('Removed old assets: ', unlinked);
      }
  });

})
```

**UPDATE**: The original project is dead but here is an up-to-date fork as of 2020: https://github.com/artemdudkin/before-build-webpack. There is also https://github.com/hashicorp/prebuild-webpack-plugin from the well-known hashicorp organization.

Comment: I hope this helps someone because it took me forever to figure out!

Comment: You definitely saved me a lot of time, thank you! @Chris W.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks. 2 tiny modifications to add to your code sample: buildDir should end with a trailing /, and adding `const fs = require('fs');` at the beginning would be nice

Comment: Thank you so much @ChrisW. This saved a ton of my time! ;) Another modification to avoid deprecation warnings is to change `fs.unlink` to `fs.unlinkSync` or give a callback for the exception.

Comment: what if they have hash in filename

Comment: @MuhammadUmer it takes care of those too

Answer (score 1):

I have a build.js file which I execute with node. In that file I import the configuration of webpack from the `webpack.config.js`. I save all configuration in a variable called `config`.

```
require("shelljs/global");

var webpack = require('webpack');
var conf = require('./webpack.config.js');
var ora = require('ora');

var spinner = ora('chargement...');
spinner.start();
// I use the rm command that is provide by the module "shellsjs/global"
rm("-rf", "build");

webpack(conf, function(err, stats){
    spinner.stop();
    if(err) throw error
    process.stdout.write(stats.toString({
        color:true,
        modules:false,
        children:false,
        chunk: false,
        chunkModule:false
    }) + '\n')
})
```

Comment: `require("shelljs/global");` and `rm("-rf", "build");` worked as expected! Neat trick. My `build` directory gets rebuilt upon command.