# CSS file won't rebuild after commenting out file when using extract-text-webpack-plugin

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am trying to extract CSS into its own file when imported into a JavaScript file. The initial build works fine, but when I am watching the files, and I comment out the line that imports the css (`import './test.css';`), webpack only rebuilds the JS file, and the CSS file (`main.css`) is not updated (it leaves the styles in the stylesheet).

**When I comment out the css import, how can I get the css file to rebuild?**

---

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: './index.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'static'),
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: "style-loader",
                    use: "css-loader"
                })
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('main.css')
    ],
};
```

---

**index.js**

```
// If I comment out the following import while the watch is running,
// it will not remove the CSS from main.css
import './test.css';

document.body.innerText = 'Hello';
```

---

**test.css**

```
body {
    background: lightcoral;
}
```

Comment: Duplicate?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40370749/how-to-remove-old-files-from-the-build-dir-when-webpack-watch

Comment: @lukas-reineke, that's an interesting idea I can look into, but my expectation is that the file (`main.css`) would simply be empty, not deleted. If it was deleted, it would cause a 404 on the HTML page.

Comment: I see. But the default behaviour if you start webpack with the line commented out, the css file wouldn't be created right? This makes it pretty complicated